# ui-bootstrap scrolling tabs: prevent first tab from moving

Tags: css, angular-ui

i have created a scrolling tabset using ui-bootstrap

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R3bHoRwD2Xf7gUUc6g7K?p=preview)

**I need the first tab to always show even when scrolling**

Thank's alot

Avi

My code:

```
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <tab-heading>

        <div class="img-thumbnail center-block TypeItem">
            <div class="typeTitle">{{tab.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </tab-heading>
    <div class='tab-content'>{{tab.content}}</div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

CSS:

```
      .nav li {
          display:table-cell !important;
          float: none !important;

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***CSS***

```
.nav li {
  margin-left:100px; 
  left:136px;
}

.nav li:first-child{
  position:fixed;
  left:-100px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:#515151;
}
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fHGofrtEiH6eG4PtpOjE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using 'position:absolute' too.
like

```
.nav li {
  margin-left:100px; 
  left:136px;
}

.nav li:first-child{
  position:absolute;
  left:-100px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:#515151;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 150px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS (require jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    var wrap = $('.typeLineBgHolder');
    var nav = wrap.find('.nav');
    var liFixed = nav.find('li').eq(0);

    wrap.scroll(function() {
        var leftPos = Math.abs(nav.offset().left);
        liFixed.css({left: leftPos + 'px'});
    });
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jrt9pFn2waZjnsEPmjf?p=preview)